# Converting NAD27 geographic to grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-9.3

I have a series of lat/long coordinates in NAD27 that i need to convert to NAD27 zone 17n eastings/northings. I have ARCGIS 9.3 but no direct and reliable means for the transformation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

your data probably needs to be in UTM NAD27 zone 17 N ( EPSG:26717)

this projection is available in ArcGIS 9.3, so you can use  the "project" tool to change the refence system. (no transformation needed because you are in the same datum)

for UTM projection based on a list of coordinates , you can use [earthpoint](http://www.earthpoint.us/convert.aspx) (batch mode available)